# Creating our own mail server using Delphi

Tags: delphi, smtp, delphi-xe2, indy

I have seen many examples in Delphi for creating Email sending applications, where we have to give a mail server to send using Tidsmtp and tidmessage which works perfectly with any mail server with small modification.

What about creating our own TIdsmtpserver. I only want to send email and i don't care about receiving emails. Is there any examples in indy 10.5.8 (XE2) to create our own smtpserver for without any help from Service providers.

Comment: What do you mean by "reviving" emails?

Comment: In that case, your question is confusing.  `TIdSMTPServer` is specifically meant for "receiving" emails from clients. You say you do not want to receive emails.  so what *DO* you want exactly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a `TIdSMTPServer` demo available in the [demo zip file](http://indy.fulgan.com/ZIP/Indy10demo.zip) on Indy's Fulgan mirror.

Comment: Thanks but how to set email ID , username and password

Comment: When a client logs in to `TIdSMTPServer`, the `OnUserLogin` event is triggered so you can validate the credentials. If accepted, the `LoggedIn` and `Username` properties of `TIdSMTPServerContext` are filled in accordingly. The `OnMsgReceive` event is triggered when an email is received. You can load the supplied `TStream` into a `TIdMessage` (due to limitations, you have to use `TIdMessageClient` and `TIdIOHandlerStreamMsg` instead of using `TIdMessage.LoadFromStream()`, where `TIdIOHandlerStreamMsg.EscapeLines` is set to True), then you can manipulate the `TIdMessage` as needed.