# Demo code indy mail server ( TIdsmtpserver)

Tags: delphi, indy10

I need to send e mail's inside a larger company network. Sending mails via the INDY smtp component is no problem and works fine for me. The only draw back about the configuration as I need a company mailbox and password shared within the source code. If I use a google mail box also everybody with access to the source code may send e mails using this account.

I wonder now wheather a own E mail server (TIdSMTPserver)  will solve my issues, as I can define the password for sending  Email by myself and I can create a sending name like "ShortNewsUpdate.com"

I already found [INDY SMTP SERVER#1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499524/using-indy-smtpserver) and  [INDY SMTP SERVER#2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8485203/creating-our-own-mail-server-using-delphi)with a link to the demo file , but the demo zip file does not compile with latest INDY library (http://indy.fulgan.com/ZIP/Indy10demo.zip )

is the a new public sample code for a mail server with Indy 10 ?

Comment: Or just don't hardcode passwords but read them from a file / enter them via a gui?

Comment: Don't matter which server you use (your own or other), people with access to the source code will know the password to send emails if you hard code it in your application. The same is true for people with a sniffer on a client machine. As @The_Fox says, don't hardcode passwords, or even the smtp server host or username. Ask the user for them and store/read it from a file/registry/whatever.

Comment: If someone gets my company e mail password or login account passwort  I'm in deep trouble, getting the access to the "small smtp mail server" he can only send e mails with this/his adress, this does not hurt me to much. I expext also better scripting options while working with my own e mail server ... still looking therefore for some code